# Using html.eex templates in server-side JS. How can I not have 2 copies of the same template?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I render some number of items server-side when the page is requested, then other items are added in real-time with JS.

```
<div>
  <%= item.attr %>
</div>
```

Then in JS it's like this:

```
channel.on("event", function(res) {
  list.append(`
    <div>
      ${res.item.attr}
    </div>
  `)
})
```

The template here is trival for demonstration, but the real thing is quite long. I dont really want to have it copied in two places.

All I can think of is:

- render the HTML server-side, return it in the JSON, then append `json.html`. The issue here is that I have current_user specific stuff.
- grab the last item in the list and do a replace on the data, though this still requires the .eex file and JS to stay in sync manually.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grabbing the data in the controller, you can just grab it and send it down to the user when the first connect to the channel. Then continue sending new data to the user as it appears. Something along the lines of

```
## my_channel.ex
def join("my_channel:" <> some_id, params, socket) do
  items = Repo.all(some_query)

  resp = %{items: Phoenix.View.render_many(items, ItemView, "items.json")}
  {:ok, resp, socket}
end
```

This way, you are still only handling the rendering of your items in your JavaScript.

Also, because of the fact that internet can go out for various reasons, you might want to think about keeping track of the more recent item that has been seen. This way, you can send that to the server on connect of the channel and be able to only get the new information instead of resending everything back down to the user, which would end up in duplicates.